# Read data from excel file to postgres database (Active Record)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am building a web application that shows stock data trends and stock quotes. The data has been sent to me in an excel file and I now need to load it into the database. The excel file has daily stock data for each stock, with columns in this format:

date | bid | offer | price | volume

And each stock is in a separate work sheet in the file, as below, each block is a worksheet:

Stock1 | Stock2 | Stock3 | Stock4

What is the best way for me to load this data from the excel spreadsheet to my DailyQuotes table, the migration file for my DailyQuotes table is below:

```
class CreateDailyQuotes < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :daily_quotes do |t|
      t.date :date
      t.decimal :bid
      t.decimal :offer
      t.decimal :price
      t.integer :volume
      t.integer :stock_id

  t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

I have already created a Stocks table with the StockName and ID as columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gem 'spreadsheet' maybe the best choice to parse old excel format 'xls'. Check this [guide](http://spreadsheet.rubyforge.org/files/GUIDE_txt.html)

And if you want to deal with xlsx, maybe [rubyXL](https://github.com/gilt/rubyXL) is better.

Answer (score 4):

I like [roo](https://github.com/hmcgowan/roo).  It works with both xls and xlsx formats.
That said, the sample code in the official documentation is good enough for your case.  You'll need to do the following:

- Iterate through each sheet
- Iterate through each row
- Create a `Stocks` object and populate fields from each row
- Save

An alternate solution is to save your excel as csv, and use [faster_csv gem](https://github.com/JEG2/faster_csv) which allows you to directly populate your db tables from the csv file.